# Issue calling java with os.system function in Python 3.4

Tags: java, python

I have a pretty simple yet frustrating issue with Python. I'm trying to call a java program from Python on Windows. Below is what I'm using:

```
os.system("java -classpath .  HW4")
```

I'm getting the class not found exception even though I've verified that I'm in the correct directory and am able to execute this line in the dos prompt.

Comment: Is it not able to find `HW4.class` or some other class?

Comment: That's what it's saying but the file is there

Comment: Have you tried using `subprocess`?

Comment: tried on my OS X but couldn't reproduce...

Comment: I haven't tried subprocess. Another note is that I'm able to execute the compile command (os.system("javac HW4,java"). I think it's something to do with the classpath command line arg not being recognized correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downgraded to a 2.7 version of Python and it works now